# How to upgrade PHP version in Windows?

Tags: php, windows, wamp

I'm using the WAMP server (x64 in windows) and recently upgraded my PHP version by downloading and installing the files from [Wamp Server Files](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/)

I configured apache and changed php.ini file for needed extensions and it's working very well.

When I go to localhost -> phpinfo (in WAMP Server), It shows me the version as `7.3.4` which means PHP upgrade is working on the server.

But, when I run `php -v` on CMD, I get the version as 7.0.10 (My previous version).

I tried these things

- WAMP server tray icon (Right click) -> Change PHP CLI version -> 7.3.4
- Adding PHP 7.3.4 path to the PATH variables (It's `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.3.4`)

But, still it does not work.

Then, I tried `where php` in CMD.

It gave me this result.

```
C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.10\php.exe
C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.3.4\php.exe
```

In PATH variables, there's `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.3.4\php.exe` which I added. But, there is no `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.10\php.exe`. Where does it come from?

If I could remove that, I think I could solve the problem.

Or is there any other way that I can solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the way to fix the problem.

In windows, there are two path variables.

1. User PATH Variables
2. System PATH Variables

PHP 7.0.10 variable was in User PATH variables. Removing it fixed the problem.

Comment: This is not the solution for my issue, however thank you Supun for the solution.

Answer (score -1):

i just uninstall the xampp and download the latest version to resolve problem